# How to pass echo statement and variable value to url using php

Tags: php

I want pass my Default message as well as variable value in url using php. My code not working with default message..
My code here:

```
 $alertmsg= "Your verification code is $password \r\n";

 $url = "http://01.50.92.51/api/smsapi.aspx?username=xxxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&to=$mobiles&from=xxxx&message=$alertmsg";

    $ch  = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Please anyone help me.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: With default message not working.. Without that message working fine.. Default message is "Your verification code is"

Comment: Did you tried URL encode it first before including it to your url ? See [PhP URL encode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the parameters in this way.

```
 $alertmsg= "Your verification code is $password \r\n";
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "message=" . urlencode($alertmsg));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your message variable this way

```
$alertmsg= "Your verification code is $password \r\n";
$url = "http://01.50.92.51/api/smsapi.aspx?username=xxxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&to=$mobiles&from=xxxx&message=".$alertmsg;
```